# Need help with Remote Event Receiver / Debugging with Azure Bus Service

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to add a simple event receiver for a Contacts list.

I added the event receiver for on Item being added.

Here is my simple code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers;

namespace LeaveRequestWeb.Services
{
public class RemoteEventReceiver1 : IRemoteEventService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles events that occur before an action occurs, such as when a user adds or deletes a list item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties">Holds information about the remote event.</param>
    /// <returns>Holds information returned from the remote event.</returns>
    public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties 
    properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

        using (ClientContext clientContext = 
     TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles events that occur after an action occurs, such as after a user adds an item to a list or deletes an item from a list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties">Holds information about the remote event.</param>
    public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        string firstName = Convert.ToString(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["FirstName"]);
        int listItemId = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId;
        Guid listId = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId;
        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Web web = clientContext.Web;
                    List list = web.Lists.GetById(listId);
                    ListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
                    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    item["FirstNamePhonetic"] = "olan Phonetic";
                    item.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception oops)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(oops.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm just updating the value of `FirstNamePhonetic` but nothing happens.

Also even though I added the connection string of my azure namespace , I can't seem to manage it to debug ! I have tried everything but still get this message :

> Cannot register Services/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc on Microsoft Azure
>   Service Bus: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal
>   Server Error.

Any ideas how to fix these two issues?